# Hyper-V console only works on Server 2012R2 and not on Server 2016

Tags: windows-server-2016, failovercluster, windows-server-core, hyper-v-server-2016

I am facing an issue connecting to the 2016 Hyper-V host from my Server 2016 Jump server. The connection works fine on 2012R2 machines. Listing the details

1. Hyper V host running on Server 2016 Core Edition.
2. Failover cluster connection works on server 2016 jump server but I am unable to view the remote console of the VM with same WinRM service error
3. Enable-PSRemoting –Force didn't help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCugR.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NR34K.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.